# How to get an integer as a string

Tags: c, string, int

I'm trying to return a string, which is the year.

This code is no where near my GUI layer, as such I'm attempting the following

```
#define COMPANY_COPYRIGHT            "Copyright © " + getYear() + ";
```

And when it is called I have

```
void getCopyRight(BSTR* copyRight) 
{
    CString CopyRightStr    =   (CString)COMPANY_COPYRIGHT;
}
```

I'm struggling with my getYear() function

```
#include <time.h>

const char getYear()
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

    int year = timeinfo->tm_year + 1900;

    char buf[8];               //I think 8 as I expect only 4 characters, each is 2 bit

    sprintf(buf,"%d", year);   //I can see year shows 2015. But not sure why it's %d because this should be the output format, surely it should be %s but this errors

    return buf;                //I can see buf shows 2015
}
```

The above errors with

```
'return' : cannot convert from 'char[4] to 'const char'
```

I understand the error message but not what to do. If I add a cast, such as

```
    return (const char)buf;                //I can see buf shows 2015
```

Then it seems to return a single ASCII character, which isn't what I want.

All I want is, instead of returning 2015 as an int, it returns only the value "2015" as a 'string'...

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all if this is C. Are you sure this isn't C++? Consider making that macro a local variable, or if not possible, at least make it a proper macro: `#define COMPANY_COPYRIGHT ( CString("Copyright © ") + getYear() )`. (assuming C++, otherwise the macro is nonsense)

Comment: The duplicate cited is what I'm doing!

Comment: There are multiple issues: the type `char` is a single character, returning a pointer to a local variable is invalid, `4` is not enough to store a 4 character string. I suggest you reading a good C book.

Comment: `strptime`, `snprintf` might be useful functions, once you corrected your undefined behavior issues.

Comment: You added a comment *I think 8 as I expect only 4 characters, each is 2 bit*. Not, that's not true, you need at least `buf[5]` because C strings are null-terminated. As I said, go read a good C book, it's worth spending the time.

Comment: @YuHao, yes, agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping aside any other issue, your code produces [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), at least.

In your `getYear()` function, you're trying to return the address of a local variable `buf`. This is not possible.

Instead, you can

- define `buf` as `char` pointer.
- allocate memory dyncamiccly using `malloc()`/`calloc()`
- use and return `buf` from `getYear()`
- use the returned pointer in the caller.

<del>That said, if I understood your question correctly, you can make use of [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) to convert a *string* to `int`. You need to change your function signature also.</del>

---

EDIT:

OK, I got it wrong regarding the conversion part, what you want is to convert an `int` to a *string*. Your best bet is [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)

Comment: Yes, I am doing that, but, it was the pointer bit which was the answer. I thought the pointer to a char would be a pointer to that single character :( ... Any way, thanks